# Why can't X be used as a function?

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

Sorry for the messy codebase. I am new to C++.

I'm trying to tie a loop and function together. (1) A moisture sensor and (2) a servo to turn a lever on and off based on moisture.

**I'm receiving an error that 'servo' cannot be used as a function.** I've tried changing servo to some other name. I'm not using servo anywhere else, such as a variable, so that doesn't seem like the issue.

Does anyone have any other advice?

```
#include "Servo.h"

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo

int pos = 0; // servo position variable
#define SensorPin A0 
float sensorValue = 0; 
bool lever = 0; // soil moisture sensor variable; 0 = dry; 1 = wet;
bool pump = 0; // pump is set to 0, which = off

// servo function
void servo(bool);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // soil moisture sensor setup
  myservo.attach(9); // servo setup
}

// soil moisture sensor loop
void loop() { 
  for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) { 
    sensorValue = sensorValue + analogRead(SensorPin); 
    delay(20);
  } 
  sensorValue = sensorValue/100.0; 
  Serial.print("Moisture level: ");
  Serial.print(sensorValue);
  Serial.print(";");
  
  if(sensorValue > 1000) {
    lever = 0; // dry
  }

  if(sensorValue < 1000) {
    lever = 1; // wet
  }

  switchOnOff(lever);
  
  delay(1000);
}

// define the servo function
void switchOnOff(bool lever) {
  Serial.print(" Lever: ");
  Serial.print(lever);
  Serial.print(";");

  Serial.print(" Pump: ");
  Serial.print(pump);
  Serial.println(";");
  
  if(lever == 0 && pump == 0) { // it is dry and pump is off, pump needs to be turned on
    for (pos = 90; pos <= 180; pos++) { // goes from 0 degrees to 90 degrees
      // in steps of 1 degree
      myservo.write(pos);             // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
      delay(15);
    }
    delay(4000);
    for (pos = 180; pos >= 90; pos--) { // goes from 90 degrees to 0 degrees
      // in steps of 1 degree
      myservo.write(pos);             // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
      delay(15);
    }
    pump = 1; // noting that pump is on
  }

  if(lever == 0 && pump == 1) { // it is dry and pump is on
    return; // do nothing, return
  }

  if(lever == 1 && pump == 1) { // it is wet and pump is on, pump needs to be turned off
    for (pos = 90; pos <= 180; pos++) { // goes from 90 degrees to 0 degrees
      // in steps of 1 degree
      myservo.write(pos);             // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
      delay(15);
    }
    delay(4000);
    for (pos = 180; pos >= 90; pos--) { // goes from 0 degrees to 90 degrees
      // in steps of 1 degree
      myservo.write(pos);             // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
      delay(15);
    }
    pump = 0; // noting that pump is off
  }

  if(lever == 1 && pump == 0) { // it is wet and pump is off
    return; // do nothing, return
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does `Servo.h` have a declaration or prototype for the `servo` function? Is what you've shown all one file? Assuming `Servo.h` has a prototype you need to include it before you try to use it, like at the top of the file. Alternatively you could move the definition of the function `servo` above everywhere you use it.

Comment: `I have yet to arrange the code base with the ints upfront and setups together`. Why don't you do that first, get your code organise.

Comment: @hcheung Sound advice. Done.

Comment: @peyo check the latest edit to the answer, had some typos to correct. Sorry for that

Comment: I would not recommend naming any function or variable you define as `servo` given that you are using a library by that name. The chance of a conflict is high. Choose a less generic name. For example, `pumpServo` or whatever accurately describes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in that you try to use the `servo()` function before properly declaring it. First, you need to declare a function before it can be mentioned in your code. Second, your definition for the `servo()` is incorrect. The `int servo(lever)`, where `lever` is not a type. You should look toward the following: `int servo(bool lever);`, where `lever` is a parameter of type `bool` which the `servo()` function takes.

Then, your function does not return anything, it only has some *"side-effects"* such as `myservo.write(pos);`. So, it should be `void`.

Try the following arrangement:

```
#include "Servo.h"

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo
// twelve servo objects can be created on most boards

// Declare the function
void servo(bool);

int pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position
#define SensorPin A0 
float sensorValue = 0; 
bool lever = 0; // lever is global variable of type bool


void setup() {
  myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object    
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}


void loop() { 
  for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) { 
    sensorValue = sensorValue + analogRead(SensorPin); 
    delay(1); 
  } 
  sensorValue = sensorValue/100.0; 
  Serial.println(sensorValue); 
  delay(30);
  
  if(analogRead(0 > 100)) {
    lever = 1;
  }

  if(analogRead(0 < 100)) {
    lever = 0;
  }

  servo(lever);
}


// Define the function
void servo(bool lever) {
  if(lever == 1) { // On
    for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) { // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
      // in steps of 1 degree
      myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    }
  }
  if(lever == 0) { // Off
    for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) { // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
      myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    } 
  }
}
```

P.S. There was also a mess with `setup()` being redefined here and there.

Comment: Thank you. The code compiles now.
Does it matter where we add the `delay(1800);`?
Edited the codebase above based on your suggestions.

Comment: @peyo it matters, but depends on the logic of what you want to achieve. If you want to make controller to be delayed before each iteration of the `loop()` then just place it at the bottom of the `loop()` as you did in your question edit.